# Declare int array of 0 using int instead of const int

Tags: c++, arrays

I am coding in c++.

If I want to declare an int array of let's say 100 long all comprised of 0, I know you can do it using cont int like so

```
const int N = 100;
int array[N] = {0};
```

Which of course works, but i need to do it using an int, and i've seen multiple post on stack overflow stating you cannot do it when defining N as an int.

My issue is I would like to declare arrays comprised of 0 of an unknown size, with the size coming from a function from the library htslib faidx_seq_len() which takes as input a DNA file in a .fasta format and the function returns an int, as such i am not able to change this return format so i am trying to cast it into const it.

So with the function i am using i'll do this:

```
// seq_ref & chr_name -> variables i get when loading the sequence file i am using

int chr_len = faidx_seq_len(seq_ref,chr_name); // with chr_len being an integer of the size of a given chromosome, which could be 249250621.

int array[chr_len] = {0}; //error: variable-sized object ‘array’ may not be initialized
```

I have tried the different types of casting based on previous stackoverflow post, but i keep getting segmentation faults and i've seen multiple places that its not possible.
With examples which fails being:

```
const int N = const_cast<const int&>(chr_len);;
int frag_len[N] = {0};

// or

int frag_len[chr_len];
for (size_t i = 0; i < chr_len; i++){frag_len[i] = 0;};
```

My professor is not a big fan of using vectors, so can anyone suggest perhaps a more untraditional way of doing this declaring a int array of 0 using an int from another function?

Or it this simply not feasible.

Comment: If it is C++ indeed, then just use any appropriate container.

Comment: could you give an example? because what i've tried has failed

Comment: @Yksisarvinen true! Messed that up!

Comment: From the identifier names it looks like you’re working with htslib. A word to the wise: do *not* emulate the programming style found in these libraries, they’re *bad code!* The author is without a doubt a genius, and he knows exactly what he’s doing, but only a genius can get away with writing such dirty code. Us mere mortals need to impose discipline on our code to make it maintainable and prevent errors.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes you're probably right, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 5):

> and i've seen multiple post on stack overflow stating you cannot do it when defining N as an int.

These posts are correct.

> My professor is not a big fan of using vectors

Your professor is wrong. Use a vector. This is literally *exactly* what vectors are for.

```
auto frag_len = std::vector<int>(chr_len);
```

If you insist on avoiding `std::vector` and similar ready-made data structures, you’ll need to swallow the bitter pill and perform your own memory management. Needless to say, **this is strongly discouraged**:

```
auto p_frag_len = new int[chr_len]();

// … use it …

// Destroy it:
delete[] p_frag_len;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have been discouraged from using `std::vector`, I'll suggest a  classic heap allocation with new and delete

```
int N = 100; // or any value

int* array = new int[N];

// zero your array out
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}

// your code that works with the array goes here

// when you are done with your array, you just need to release it via scalar delete
delete [] array;
```

Old school C allocations are similar:

```
int N = 100; // or any value

int* array = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}

// your code that works with the array goes here


// release the allocated memory
free(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about declaring the array dynamically by malloc()
something like the below:

```
int i=0,n=100;
int *a = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));
if (a != NULL)
    for (i=0;i<100;i++) a[i] = 0;
```

?

Comment: Well first off, this will fail to compile in C++, which is what OP is using. Also, it leaks memory. Thirdly, why use a loop instead of `memset`?

Comment: i didnt understand the 'leak memory' remark, it will leak memory if the malloc fails, is that what you meant ?  (i changed the code above to check it) , secondly i think here the for loop is better in prformance than memset, as memset works on bytes  and the loop here works on int , so it wil run about 4 times better (or a bit more)

Comment: Leaking memory means that you allocate memory without freeing it. You are *completely wrong* concerning the performance of `memset`. If it were less efficient than a `for` loop that would be a major performance issue. In practice, `memset` will use the most efficient implementation possible for a given architecture, despite the fact that it nominally operates a byte at a time. In fact, a modern compiler [will optimise the loop](https://godbolt.org/z/7PM9jdvc6) to call `memset` instead (but there will be some additional overhead).

Comment: regarding the mem leak  because of not using free() , you are correct, but the question was not to write the whole code, it was about allocating an array and initialize it with 0 , when the array size is dynamic (i.e it is int and not const int) ,  and regarding memset() iit puzze me as when i was looking at the implementation of it i saw things like [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ics-mr0/libc/string/memset.c]  or [https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/memset.c] where the code works on byte level

Comment: On modern compilers `memset` is a builtin. The implementations you found are (a) a fallback implementation for a platform with limited support, and (b) a legacy implementation that’s basically only used for reference purposes these days. But *even if* that was the actual implementation, compilers recognise this pattern and substitute it with the compiler intrinsic for the target platform.